# Ubuntu 20.04 Audio Totally broken. There's no sound and detects headphones all the time

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I've a big problem. The sound of my pc has a lot of problems.

My laptop detects headphones all the time even when there is nothing plugged in.
Also doesn't make any sound when I tried to use '''pulseaudio --kill & pulseaudio --start'''  did not fix the problem. I need to use multiple times pulseaudio --kill like it was more than a pulseaudio.

In the case of pavucontrol or alsamixer I can't find any problem.
Doesn't works when I use '''alsa force-reload''' nor reinstall pulsaudio or alsa-base.
I already tried to reinstall  kernel with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Maybe a clue is when I use `systemctl --user status pulseaudio`  I get this:

[

```
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-02-24 11:01:42 CST; 16min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 36552 (pulseaudio)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/pulseaudio.service
             └─36552 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Feb 24 11:01:42 hans-Inspiron-5570 systemd[17622]: Starting Sound Service...
Feb 24 11:01:42 hans-Inspiron-5570 pulseaudio[36552]: **Failed to set volume of 'Speaker': Input/output error**
Feb 24 11:01:42 hans-Inspiron-5570 systemd[17622]: Started Sound Service.
Feb 24 11:02:20 hans-Inspiron-5570 pulseaudio[36552]: **Failed to set switch of 'Headphone'**: Input/output error
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUUc4.png)

It also happens when i use `pulsaudio` instead of `pulsaudio --start` to see the log.

I don't know what is the cause,  `pulsaudio --kill & pulsaudio --start` It was solved.

I already checked my sound card with

```
 ~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Sometimes when reinstall pulseaudio or log out it seems like it works correctly but instead of the sound is a  buzzing noise.
I appreciate any help. :(